# in my function it runs document.write 10 times what i specified

Tags: javascript, loops

when I try to run

```js
 function thing(number) {
  for (i = 1; i < number+1; i++){
      document.write(i + ' ');
  }
} 
var otherthing = prompt("");
thing(otherthing);
```

when it loops `document.write(i);` it loops 10 times more than specified
I've messed around a bit and can't get it. i'm also kind of new to JavaScript and i'm open to any other tips or feedback

Comment: `otherthing` and therefore `number` is a string ... so `'1'  + 1`  is `11` - `'2' + 1` is `21` ... you need to `thing(+otherthing);` to coerce the argument to a number

Comment: I guess @JaromandaX is playing give away credits :P

Comment: @Lokesh - I was actually trying to find a duplicate because this has been asked many times before :p

Comment: @JaromandaX let's dig and give chance others to dig :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as explained by [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x), data type of number argument on function thing is string not int, float or other number data type. So you need to change it to number first. Something like this :

```js
function thing(number) {
    for (let i = 1; i < Number(number)+1; i++){
        document.write(i + ' ');
    }
}   
var otherthing = prompt("");
thing(otherthing);
```

Comment: thanks all of these answers work. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Tell me if this works for you.

```js
function thing(aNumber) { 
  aNumber = Number(aNumber) + 1;
  for (i = 1; i < aNumber; i++){ 
    document.write(i + ' ');

    }
}   
var otherthing = prompt(""); 
thing(otherthing);
```

Edit: The reason why the code wasn't working before is because the input from the prompt was being interpreted as a string, not a number. So the `Number(aNumber)` part is really what makes this edit work, as that explicitly tells JavaScript that the variable is a number, not a string. Also, I suspect 'number' is a keyword that can't be used for variables, just like you can't use the words 'function' or 'var' as variables. So I changed it to 'aNumber' instead of 'number'.

Comment: _"I suspect 'number' is a keyword that can't be used for variables"_ - No, it is not a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords).

Answer (score 1):

Try this you forget to parse it into integer

```js
function thing(number) {
            for (i = 1; i < number+1; i++){
                document.write(i + ' ');
            }
        }   
var otherthing = parseInt(prompt(""));
thing(otherthing);
```

Otherwise you can use like this as well

```js
function thing(number) {
            for (i = 1; i < number+1; i++){
                document.write(i + ' ');
            }
        }   
var otherthing = prompt("");
thing(+otherthing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Number` for convert string to number :

```
for (i = 1; i < Number(number) + 1 ; i++) {
```

```js
function thing(number) {
  for (i = 1; i < Number(number) +1 ; i++) {
    document.write(i + ' ');
  }
} 

var otherthing = prompt("");
thing(otherthing);
```